# Error with optimalK of gap-statistic: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, k-means

I was playing around with this [kaggle kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/kitakoj18/exploring-wine-descriptions-with-nlp-and-kmeans) which is about running k-means for text clustering. I wanted to extend it by automating the identification of optimal k value for the clustering. I am trying to use [`gap-statistic`](https://anaconda.org/milesgranger/gap-stat) for this purpose.

As a first step, I had to install the package with: `conda install -c milesgranger gap-stat`

Then, I tried the following piece of code.

```
from gap_statistic import OptimalK
optimalK = OptimalK(parallel_backend='rust')
k, gapdf = optimalK(X, cluster_array=np.arange(1, 11))
```

Which ended up in this error:
*ValueError: Sparse matrices are not supported by this function. Perhaps one of the scipy.sparse.linalg functions would work instead.* I understood that I had change the last line of code to `k, gapdf = optimalK(X.toarray(), cluster_array=np.arange(1, 11))` as the optimalK function would accept numpy array.

This change handled the first error very well. And then landed in another error: *TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable*

Guessing this as an exception left unhandled inside optimalK. Despite that, is there anything I can do to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`k, gapdf = optimalK(X.toarray(), cluster_array=np.arange(1, 11))` is conflicting to the source code of OptimalK, as in [ForceBru's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56057951/3086097).

The following code change will remove the error. And it is the correct equivalent to the erroneous snippet.

```
# optimal k value
k = optimalK(X.toarray(), cluster_array=np.arange(1, 11))

# dataframe with gap values
gapdf = optimalK.gap_df.head()
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the source code](https://github.com/milesgranger/gap_statistic/blob/9020d9530d15e1ed79045e25e1ca5e6c67fa5c0c/gap_statistic/optimalK.py#L88), `OptimalK.__call__` returns *an integer* (see line 88):

```
return int(self.gap_df.loc[np.argmax(self.gap_df.gap_value.values)].n_clusters)
```

Your code attempts to unpack this integer into two objects with `k, gapdf` here:

```
k, gapdf = optimalK(X, cluster_array=np.arange(1, 11))
```

This is, of course, not possible.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer help me found out that I have mixed up between 2 different gap-statistic examples. These are the two example notebooks - [nb1](https://anaconda.org/milesgranger/gap-statistic/notebook), [nb2](https://github.com/milesgranger/gap_statistic/blob/master/Example.ipynb)